# Concatenate SQL files using Python while ignoring duplicates

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I have a directory containing a large amount of SQL files in the form of .txt files. They are used to fill a SQLite database. Instead of loading them one by one, I would like to concatenate all these files into a single text file, so I can load just one file.

The problem is that I have duplicates here and there. My txt files come from hardware tests, and from time to time I have two identical IDs. In this case, I would like to **keep the latest file** that was created. I have a `UNIQUE` constraint in my database so I have to keep one file per ID, and I want to keep the latest one.

My SQL files look like that:

```
INSERT INTO Table...
```

(~1000 lines)

And I have, say, 230 of them. So I wanted to end up with something like that:

```
INSERT INTO Table...
INSERT INTO Table...
INSERT INTO Table...
```

(~200 rows * 1000 lines)

This is the script I came up with:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Filename','Truncated filename','Content'])
for p in Path(path).glob('**/*.txt'):
    filename = p.name
    content = p.read_text()
    # Remove the 16 last characters from filename because they correspond to datetype and ".txt". Ex: 202206141707.txt
    df.loc[len(df.index)] = [filename, filename[:-16], content]
# Keep the latest value in case of duplicates -- doesn't seem to work
(df.groupby('Truncated filename', as_index=False).apply(lambda x: x if len(x) == 1 else x.iloc[[-1]]).reset_index(level=0, drop=True))
# Sort the dataframe
sort = df.sort_values("Truncated filename", axis=0, ascending=False)
# Concatenate the "Conten" column in a text file
output_text = df['Content'].str.cat(sep=' ')
# Write the output file
with open(output_path, 'w') as f:
    f.write(output_text)
```

My logic was the following:

- Get all files from directory
- Make a dataframe with filename and content as columns ("Truncated Filename" columns helps me find duplicates)
- Remove duplicates while keeping the last value each time
- Concatenate all of "content" column in a text file
- Write that text file
- Import it in my database

However, it doesn't seem to work. When I load the output file in my database, I still have rows failing the UNIQUE constraint.

If you have an idea to solve this problem with another approach, it is welcome too.

Comment: assuming you are in a single transaction, define yours unique constraint as DEFERRABLE, before to run script. Should work! take a look at [SQLite Foreign Key Support](https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html)

Comment: @UrielAlves Thank you! I didn't know DEFERRABLE. I'm currently re-running the script, we'll see if it loads correctly.